# GatsbyJS and Contentful: How to link from one page to another, other than from the index page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, contentful, gatsby

I have made a query in an 'AllRecipes' page, that is NOT the index of my site. Using the data pulled from the query, I have created links to blogposts on different pages. This works when the links are created in the index page. However, when I try this from the 'AllRecipes' page, I get this error:

[image]

I don't want to create a component for this page in my site directory at src/pages/All..., because I am using a blogpost template in the template folder, that grabs the required blogpost data from Contentful. However, I don't know what could create the bond between a slug of:

> /AllRecipes/schwarzwälder-kirschtorte

and my blogpost template. Right now, it will only work if I search for:

> /schwarzwälder-kirschtorte

, from the index page.

Is there a way to say: /AllRecipes/schwarzwälder-kirschtorte is equal to /schwarzwälder-kirschtorte, or some other way to resolve this problem?

Here is the code for my 'AllRecipes' component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'

const BlogPost = ({node}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={node.slug}>{node.postTitle}</Link>
    </li>
  )
}

const AllRecipes = ({data}) => (
  <ul className="blog-post">
    {data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge, i) => 
      <BlogPost key={i} node={edge.node} />
    )}
  </ul>
)

export default AllRecipes

export const recipeQuery = graphql`
  query recipeQuery {
    allContentfulBlogPost (
      filter: {
        node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}
    },
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          postTitle 
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {
   const { createPage } = boundActionCreators
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blog-post.js`)
     // Query for markdown nodes to use in creating pages.
     //all entries based on content type: which here, is blog
       resolve(
           graphql(`
               {
                   allContentfulBlogPost (limit:100) {
                       edges {
                           node {
                               id
                               slug
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           `).then((result) => {
               if (result.errors) {
                   reject(result.errors)
           }

           // Create blog post pages.
           result.data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.forEach((edge) => {
               createPage({
                   path: edge.node.slug, // required
                   component: blogPostTemplate,
                   context: {
                     slug: edge.node.slug,
                   }
                 })
               })

           return
         })
       )
   })
}
```

Comment: Can you post your gatsby-node.js?

Comment: Hey, i added my gatsby-node.js to my post :)

Comment: aaahh, okay i wrote: `AllRecipes/${edge.node.slug}` in my path:, instead of edge.node.slug, and now it's working :) thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Comment: No worries, good luck with your app. The cake is delicious I'm sure